# Google Script - if error, return null and move to next row

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

Currently the script works totally fine but has one issue, every time there is an error, it stops, then I have to delete that row with error and run the script again.

What I want is, if there is an error then it should return the results as null and then move to next line item, so that there is no manual interruption.

```js
function getSearchAnalytics(){
  var service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
     for(var i=7;i<525;i++){
    var site = s_searchAnalytics.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
       if (!site){
      continue;
      return null
    }
      
           
    var apiURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/' + URLDecode(site) + '/searchAnalytics/query?fields=rows&alt=json';
   
    
    var lastRow = s_searchAnalytics.getLastRow();
    s_searchAnalytics.getRange(i,2,lastRow,5).clear();
    
    var headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + getService().getAccessToken()};
    
    var payload = {
      "startDate" : startDate,
      "endDate" : endDate,
      "dimensions" : ["device"],
      "rowLimit" : "25000"
    };
    
    var options = {
      "headers": headers,
      "contentType":'application/json',
      "method" : "post",
      "payload" : JSON.stringify(payload),
      "muteHttpExceptions": true
    };
    
    try {
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiURL, options);
    } 
       
    catch (e) {
      Logger.log(e);
    }
    Logger.log(response)
if (!response){
      continue;
      return null
    }
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
     
     if (result.error){
      Browser.msgBox(result.error.errors[0].message);
      return null
    }
    
    var row = []
    for (var k in result.rows){
      row.push([
        result.rows[k].keys[0], 
        result.rows[k].metric1, 
        result.rows[k].metric2, 
        result.rows[k].metric3, 
        result.rows[k].position
      ]);
    }
    s_searchAnalytics.getRange(i,2,row.length,5).setValues(row);
          
     }} else {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s', authorizationUrl);
  }
}
```

Comment: getService() is undefined

Comment: If you don't want to stop on errors then why are you using returns?

Comment: `s_searchAnalytics` undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took ideas from both your codes and it worked. Here is the final version that's working.

```js
function getSearchAnalytics(){
  var service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
     for(var i=7;i<525;i++){
    var site = s_searchAnalytics.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
       if (!site){
      continue;
      return null
    }
      
           
    var apiURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/' + URLDecode(site) + '/searchAnalytics/query?fields=rows&alt=json';
    var startDate = Utilities.formatDate(s_searchAnalytics.getRange(2, 2).getValue(), "GMT+7", "yyyy-MM-dd");
    var endDate = Utilities.formatDate(s_searchAnalytics.getRange(3, 2).getValue(), "GMT+7", "yyyy-MM-dd");
    
    
    var lastRow = s_searchAnalytics.getLastRow();
    s_searchAnalytics.getRange(i,2,lastRow,5).clear();
    
    var headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + getService().getAccessToken()};
    
    var payload = {
      "startDate" : startDate,
      "endDate" : endDate,
      "dimensions" : ["device"],
      "rowLimit" : "25000"
    };
    
    var options = {
      "headers": headers,
      "contentType":'application/json',
      "method" : "post",
      "payload" : JSON.stringify(payload),
      "muteHttpExceptions": true
    };
    
    try {
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiURL, options);
    } 
       
    catch (e) {
      Logger.log(e);
    }
        Logger.log(response)
        if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    }
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
     
     if (result.error){
      continue;
      return null
    }
    
    var row = []
    for (var k in result.rows){
      row.push([
        result.rows[k].keys[0], 
        result.rows[k].clicks, 
        result.rows[k].impressions, 
        result.rows[k].ctr, 
        result.rows[k].position
      ]);
    }
    s_searchAnalytics.getRange(i,2,row.length,5).setValues(row);
          
     }} else {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s', authorizationUrl);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate your code and found some issues:

1. Using return statement in your loop with terminate the whole function. Instead, use only continue. In line 9 and 47: the code will never reach the `return null` because you already use continue. Continue will leave the current iteration and move to the next one.
2. Instead of using `if(!response)`, It would be easier to determine if the API call has an error by identifying the response code.

> - Informational responses (100–199)
> - Successful responses (200–299)
> - Redirects (300–399)
> - Client errors (400–499)
> - Server errors (500–599)

By using the response code, we can prevent writes if the response code is not 200(OK).

Here I modified your code:

```
function getSearchAnalytics() {
  var service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    for (var i = 7; i < 525; i++) {
      var site = s_searchAnalytics.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      if (!site) {
        continue;
      }else{
        var apiURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/' + URLDecode(site) + '/searchAnalytics/query?fields=rows&alt=json';
        var startDate = Utilities.formatDate(s_searchAnalytics.getRange(2, 2).getValue(), "GMT+7", "yyyy-MM-dd");
        var endDate = Utilities.formatDate(s_searchAnalytics.getRange(3, 2).getValue(), "GMT+7", "yyyy-MM-dd");

        var lastRow = s_searchAnalytics.getLastRow();
        s_searchAnalytics.getRange(i, 2, lastRow, 5).clear();
        var headers = {
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + getService().getAccessToken()
        };

        var payload = {
          "startDate": startDate,
          "endDate": endDate,
          "dimensions": ["device"],
          "rowLimit": "25000"
        };

        var options = {
          "headers": headers,
          "contentType": 'application/json',
          "method": "post",
          "payload": JSON.stringify(payload),
          "muteHttpExceptions": true
        };

        try {
          var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiURL, options);
        } catch (e) {
          Logger.log(e);
        }
        Logger.log(response)
        if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
          var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
          var row = []
          for (var k in result.rows) {
            row.push([
              result.rows[k].keys[0],
              result.rows[k].clicks,
              result.rows[k].impressions,
              result.rows[k].ctr,
              result.rows[k].position
            ]);
          }
          s_searchAnalytics.getRange(i, 2, row.length, 5).setValues(row);
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s', authorizationUrl);
  }
}
```

### Reference:

[HTTP response status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)